# kendo combobox dropdown border color

Tags: combobox, border, kendo-ui

According to my requirement I have changed the background color of kendo combobox but the border(in old coloor) still remains.
How do i remove/change the border color of dropdown(complete dropdown not individual list items) in kendo combobox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following CSS would set the combobox and its dropdown menu border:

```
.k-combobox {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.k-list-container {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/igocak/1/edit